# Trying to use LIKE operator on Integer

Tags: sql-server

I'm currently trying to implement a filtering system to my application using an SQL query. Filter works fine but I'm trying to cover all possibilities, one of which is that I would like it so using my sub-string option I am able to retrieve more than 1 value if I have more IDs with 1. How exactly do I go about doing that with my query? I saw cast is an option and tried to add but it doesn't seem to be working, these are my two versions:

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM DeDomain1 e, DeDomain2 c WHERE e.studentId = c.id "  
            "AND CAST e.studentId AS VARCHAR AND (:studentId is null OR e.studentId LIKE '%' + :studentId + '%')"...)
```

I attempted to add CAST but it doesn't seem to be working, with the error consisting of an QuerySyntaxException. I would therefore assume I've done it wrong/wrote it wrong, if that is the case, does anyone know how I have done it wrong?

Comment: which db you are using ??

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Please show the structure of the table your are querying, sample data in that table, and an example of the desired result set from your query.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this syntax:

```
@Query("SELECT e.*
   FROM DeDomain1 e, 
   DeDomain2 c 
   WHERE e.studentId = c.id
   AND (:studentId is null 
        OR cast(e.studentId AS VARCHAR(10)) LIKE concat('%' ,:studentId , '%')))")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but got this: expecting CLOSE, found '('

Comment: I broke it down a bit and found that the concat part is fine, but when adding the cast function it seems to keep saying it's missing a ).

Comment: @softtouch Something missing after `VARCHAR(10)` :) Really, you should find editor, which displays matching braces.

Comment: "CAST(e.studentID AS VARCHAR(10) ) LIKE"  You didn't close your CAST()

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

@Query("SELECT e FROM DeDomain1 e, DeDomain2 c WHERE e.studentId = c.id "
            "AND (:studentId is null OR e.studentId LIKE '%' + :CONVERT(varchar(10), studentId )+ '%')")